# Форма HTML + jquery для отправки rest запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть контроллер на java обрабатывающий post запрос.

На фронте есть форма где пользователь вводит какое-то слово и это слово прямо во время ввода начиная с 1 буквы автоматически обрабатывается на контроллере и под формой выводиться ответ json string.

мой rest контроллер возвращает подсказки - возможные адреса из БД на вводимое слово пользователем.

например он начинает вводить "моск"
ему выводятся всякие московские проспекты и прочее.

можете подсказать или скинуть пример как это на html + jquery запилить?

Comment: Смотрите событие `onInput()` или `$(selector).on("input", f)`. Событие вызывает функцию отправки запроса на сервер. Полученные данные рендерит в подсказках. Изи.

Comment: оке попробую. просто фронт темный лес для меня)